# Where can I find dataset for University acceptance rate for college athletes?

Tags: data-request, education

I'm looking for some data sets so that I can import them into my database and do some data analytics with that data. The main dataset I'm looking for is the University acceptance rate, the GPA of the accepted student, and whether or not that student is accepted for an athletic sport.

I'd like to do some analytics to see whether or not having an athletic ability gives you an upper hand when getting into some big-name schools even though the GPA and acceptance requirements are much lower than of the accepted students who won't be playing in an athletic sport.

I have looked around and have found very little information. Most of the datasets show the total averages for some universities. I'd like to get a list of reported GPAs for each university and whether or not they will be playing a sport.

If the data set provides more information, that's even better! Any links I can take a look at will also be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible options:
[Student-Athlete Experiences Data Archive](https://www.icpsr.umich.edu/icpsrweb/content/NCAA/data.html)
[Stanford University Common Data Sets (CDS)](http://ucomm.stanford.edu/cds/2015)

This article has data for PAC-10:
[Comparing the Acceptance Rates of Athletes to the General Public](http://thehuskyhaul.com/2012/05/16/comparing-the-acceptance-rates-of-athletes-to-the-general-public/)

[U.S. DOE's EADA (Equity in Athletics Data Analysis)](https://ope.ed.gov/athletics/#/) looks promising, but after a quick look, it actually has very little useful information in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks, those sites have a lot of useful information. I'll try to compile together what I'm looking for. I might have to get different data sets and combine it to get what I need.